# drawing arrows on a line defined by a set of points( for tracking)

Tags: java, graphics, dictionary, applet

> I have a set of points which define a route 
>    and I must draw them so a vehicle's moving direction is denoted.
>    The points may be from a curve and I need to draw some arrows.
>    I want to draw arrows on the route to define which arrow vehicle goes.
>   I have a mapviewr java applet and the last I must do is this work, I want to define arrows on every 10 points on the route.
>   A thing like this:
>   [alt text http://img517.yfrog.com/img517/7690/schermafbeelding2010032.png](http://img517.yfrog.com/img517/7690/schermafbeelding2010032.png)

Comment: did the image come with the homework assignment?

Comment: So the text is from a homework assignment. Please tag it as homework.

Comment: i am working on an AVL project and it is not a homwork, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at Java2D shapes :they allow you to define any kind of ... well ... shape and draw them on a given path. You can take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Java2D-Tutorial.html) or at [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Riduidel said you should also try to get the angle that results from the intersection of the line with OX. Using that angle you could calculate a transformation matrix to draw the arraws neatly aligned to the line.

Answer (score 0):

[Pete Kirkham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527/pete-kirkham) posted [a full working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027613/how-to-draw-a-directed-arrow-line-in-java/2027641#2027641) a few months ago in [How to draw a directed arrow in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027613/how-to-draw-a-directed-arrow-line-in-java)