# How can I make driving navigation app on Android

Tags: android

How can I draw an Arrow showing the driving direction in MapView ?.

Comment: Take a look at this answer
[How do I draw an arrowhead (in Android)?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android/6713978#6713978

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways

1. you can probably override onDraw method in mapview
2. make ur item draw over the mapview making use of [frame layout.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `ItemizedOverlay`. Something like this: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/bazaaroid/com/bazaaroid/mobile/MapItemOverlay.java.htm

More info here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html