# Draw arrow dynamically ina android

Tags: android

I am developing an app , in which i want to make diff shapes like arrow,rectangles, lines, free draw etc dynamically on finger touch, i am able to draw line, free draw, rectangles but i am not getting the arrow.i also search a lot on google but didn't find anythng relevant.Please suggest if someone has a solution.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be a 9 drawable arrow that is expanded as they draw... you'd just have to set the angle as their finger moved...

Comment: @RyanInBinary That's not a bad idea. You might lose some quality if you rotate though..

Comment: That's a good point Samuel, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Che this : [drawing arrowhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android)

Comment: @ Imran Rana: This is just making an arrow head

Answer (score 2):

Create a [path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) object in an arrow shape using the [moveTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#moveTo%28float,%20float%29), and [lineTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#lineTo%28float,%20float%29) methods.

Comment: @nehaneema Imran Rana already commented with a great link that tells you how to use a Path. You can apply the same logic to draw the rest of the arrow.

Comment: I used the following code it makes the arrow in correct form only when i make from top to bottom, or functionally i can say only when mX > mY.i dont understand how to tackle it..