# how to create arrow from xml code

Tags: android, drawable, android-xml

In my project i need to create the frames, lines and all the shapes required from the drawable folder. I could draw a rectangle and frame and all from drawable. But the problem comes when i need to create arrows from the drawable folder.

Please help me to draw the up arrow and down arrow as shown in the images in the drawable folder.

[image: Up Arrow]
[image: Down Arrow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot draw complex shapes currently with the builtin tools android has. [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) lists all the possibilities you have for now.

Why don't you just create different sizes of the arrow in png (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi), and use those? That is the recommended way.

If you want to do custom things, you either should look into SVG, or [draw your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android).