# Drawing an arrow in android

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I draw an arrowhead (in Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android)

I am trying to make a nice layout layout in android and for that I would like to connect two views with an arrow, which looks pretty much like this:

[image: a busy cat]

So on the start of the arrow there is supposed to be a view, and at the tip of the arrow as well.

Whats the best way to achieve this? Is the easiest just to use an image? But then I could not change the color of the arrow in android for example. Can I somehow do that with shapes?

Thank you!

Comment: Many duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?q=Drawing+an+arrow+in+android

Answer (score 7):

You can use Canvas, and create your own "Arrow" view, its not too dificult, just drawLines using the right coordinates, or create a Path.

Extend `View` class, and override `onDraw(Canvas c)`, then you should paint your lines with

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
```

....

```
public void onDraw(Canvas c){
            Path path = new Path();
            path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
            path.moveTo(insideRectangleOffset, getHeight() - insideRectangleOffset);
            path.lineTo(getWidth() - insideRectangleOffset, insideRectangleOffset);
            path.lineTo(getWidth() - insideRectangleOffset, getHeight() - insideRectangleOffset);
            path.lineTo(insideRectangleOffset, getHeight() - insideRectangleOffset);
            path.close();

            c.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Replace the coordinates as your need, I've copy pasted the code from a view that I've created