# Android: draw arrow from two coordinates

Tags: android, android-canvas

I would like to replace an arrow instead of the normal lines created with a Canvas

`c.drawLine(ax, ay, bx, by, pnt);`

I have coordinate points on the screen (ax ay bx by)

Comment: I d say alittle more information is necessary

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android