# how indicate a point of a image in imageview?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I want to indicate a point of a image in imageView . (for example indicate an eye in an image of a face) 
but I dont know How do I handle it for the screens with different sizes!
please help me How do I indicate a point of image so that it is exactly the same in the screens of different sizes?! (how indicate this eye in all screens sizes)
tnx

[example: indicate a point of a image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUOab.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713757/how-do-i-draw-an-arrowhead-in-android

Comment: see `ImageView#getImageMatrix` and `Matrix` documentation