# How to draw an arrow/line between two labels in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a directed arrow line in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027613/how-to-draw-a-directed-arrow-line-in-java)

I am trying to draw a line/arrow between two labels in a JFrame. I know the particular coordinates to both of these labels marked as (x1,y1) (x2,y2). How can I draw a line/arrow between them?.

Comment: btw, your problem has nothing to do with netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

This should help http://java-sl.com/connector.html

Answer (score 0):

You actually should use some development platform IDE like Netbeans or some swing specialist IDE's, as they helps you a lot during development.
Using an IDE, you can do it as drag and drop and accordingly it will automatically generate the code.
Not only drawing a line, but you can do all the work with ease.
Try it out....

Answer (score -1):

it's not nice but it's running:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

private static JLabel a;
private static JLabel b;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Example example = new Example();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    a = new JLabel("a");
    a.setBounds(50, 50, 10, 10);

    b = new JLabel("b");
    b.setBounds(150, 150, 10, 10);

    panel.add(a);
    panel.add(b);

    example.getContentPane().add(panel);

    example.setGlassPane(new MyGlas());
    example.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

    example.setSize(400, 400);

    example.setVisible(true);
}

public static class MyGlas extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Rectangle aBounds = a.getBounds();
        Rectangle bBounds = b.getBounds();

        g.drawLine(aBounds.x, aBounds.y, bBounds.x, bBounds.y);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: : on using ur code i get an error non-static method cannot be accessed from static context from getContentPane method to setVisible. Can u please help..

Comment: If you just copy and past the code into a new class file, it works definitely. So, what have you changed? Post the code and the exact error.

Comment: in ur code m declaring jlabels as static,by doing this m getting an error for getContentPane() method that static content cannot be referenced by this method.

Comment: if you don't post your changes, I can't help you.

Comment: This is horrible coding practice and defeats the Object Oriented Programing style. Also, it is very discouraged to use a null layout.

Comment: Also, why would you paint on the glass pane? Why not just paint right on the JPanel that you already created?

Comment: It's a solution for his problem in just a couple of lines. Of course, I can create a bunch of getter- and setter-methods, some interfaces and a fancy factory. But why? To show him how to draw a line? AND: I use a null layout, so I can position the buttons where ever I want using setBounds. AND I draw on the glasspane because because it's the top pane and I have to overwrite a paint(...) method. There is no OOP practice validated, just two fields are static and public because it's less code for an example...